# Can't get numpy to import with python3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and three different python builds on the machine (python2.7, python3, python3.2). I can only get packages to import in python 2.7. Whenever I try to import them in Python 3.2.3, I get:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Jan 14 2014, 13:11:14) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

I have seen various questions around Stack with similar issues, but none of them have fixed my issue.

For example, I have ran this code:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

With this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-numpy is already the newest version.
python3-scipy is already the newest version.
```

So, it seems that I do have the packages installed for python3, but can't get them to load into the python3.2.3 environment.

```
    >>> sys.path
    ['', '/usr/local/lib/python32.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload', 
'/home/bre-dev-2/.local/lib/python3.2/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages']
```

All of the site-packages are empty, while numpy and scipy exists in the folder usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (notice there is no "local" in the path name).

And finally, when I change sys.path to contain the directory with numpy and scipy:

```
>>> sys.path[6]='/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
```

Any suggestions? Starting to lose my mind....

Comment: I know you don't want to hear a "it works for me", but I just installed `python3` and `python3-numpy` on a 12.04.1 and it works. Could it be that your `sys.path` is broken somehow?

Comment: interesting. the `sys.path` points to `usr/local/lib` while the dist-packages are in `usr/lib`...

Comment: It is normal for `/usr/local` to be in the path, at least in Debian/Ubuntu systems, because that's where you install by default system-wide non-packaged stuff. What is *not* normal (definitely) is that `/usr/lib/python3.2` is absent. Now, that *would* be possible if you're running a hand-build Python. Care to check? (`which python3`)

Comment: looks like `/usr/local/bin/python3` is the winner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the dectective work, as suspected :P, there was some other Python environment at work. Now, why is that there? :-D

If you want to use the system Python, force it with `/usr/bin/python3`. That would let you work with the Numpy you installed.

If you want to get the one under `/usr/local/bin` out of the way, just rename it so that it doesn't "shadow" the other Pythons in the system. Remember that `/usr/local/bin` takes precedence over `/usr/bin` in the path.

Comment: haha thanks. worked like a charm. i can finally breath!

Comment: any advice on how to install matplotlib? having similar issues. should I install it in the same usr/lib folder?

Comment: It all depends on how you're installing things. `easy_install`? `pip`? ...? In any case, if you're using some of those package-installing tools, make sure to run it specifically with Python you want. Eg. `/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/pip ...`